# What linting and prettifying tools do you use?

Tags: solidity, ide

I'm used to coding in JS, and I've noticed VSCode's default linting and Prettier's default auto formatting isn't working for me. For example, VSCode shows red squigglies on any and every `pragma` declaration I open with, and also won't show red squigglies when I do things like `emit` and event without arguments (when I declared it with parameters). Prettier also crashes every time I try to format, and won't, for example, add semi-colons or spaces.

Are there any tools you use for code formatting? Or any settings for my existing tools that you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I use  `Solidity visual developer`, `Solidity language support` and the `solidity` extension and they work seamlessly. There are some other linting extensions but won't recommend them if you are just beginning these are `Solidity-solhint`, `solidity Debuger` and  `solidity Extended` They are very strict and you can experience the same problems you have currently with prettier.